# How to initialise Vuelidate 2.0.0 when testing a Vue component with Vitest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate, vitest

In my Vue 2.7.14 app I'm using Vuelidate 2.0.0. I'm trying to migrate a test from Jest to Vitest, but the `v$` object is not initialised correctly in the latter case. The component has a checkbox bound to `formData.accepted`

```js
  validations () {
    return {
      formData: {
        accepted: {
          required,
          sameAs: sameAs(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Vuelidate is initialised within the component as per [the docs](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#getting-started-1)

```js
  setup () {
    return {
      v$: useVuelidate({ $autoDirty: true })
    }
  },
```

When I run the following test under Jest, it passes

```js
  it('click save button', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)

    expect(wrapper.vm.v$.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeTruthy()
    await wrapper.find('[data-cy="accept-checkbox"]').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.v$.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeFalsy()
  })
```

However, if I run the same test using Vitest it fails because `wrapper.vm.v$.formData` is `undefined` because `v$` is initialised to:

```js
v$ {
  "$dirty": false,
  "$path": "__root",
  "$model": null,
  "$error": false,
  "$errors": [],
  "$invalid": false,
  "$anyDirty": false,
  "$pending": false,
  "$silentErrors": [],
  "$validationGroups": {}
}
```

By contrast, when the Jest test is run, `$silentErrors` is not empty, and the following property path is (obviously) valid

```js
v$.formData.accepted.$invalid
```

What should I do to ensure that `v$` is initialised correctly when the test is run with Vitest?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution here? I'm seeing the same issue with no clear work-around.

Comment: @Stephen yes, I'm not sure which version of Vitest I was using when I ran into this issue, but I tried again with a later version and the problem just magically disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

**First try:**

You need to assign a const to the wrapper:

```
  it('click save button', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)
    const { $v } = wrapper.vm;

    expect(wrapper.vm.v$.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeTruthy()
    await wrapper.find('[data-cy="accept-checkbox"]').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.v$.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeFalsy()
  })
```

**Further try:**

I think you are also missing the import of `validationMixin` in your test file to use the `$v` object:

```
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate';
```

After that change your component to this:

```
export default {
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  setup () {
    return {
      v$: useVuelidate()
    }
}
```

Glad about feedback if it worked and if not we'll get there. :)

Comment: Alright, I just read your new answer. I'll take a look after work again if it's fine for you

Comment: The code in your "First try" suggestion is functionally identical to the code I'm already using (which doesn't work). The only difference is the addition of an unused  `$v` variable

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but your answer assumes I'm using Vuelidate 0.X, but I'm actually using 2.0, which has a very different API e.g. the validationMixin you mention no longer exists https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/migration_guide.html#removal-of-validationmixin

Comment: I already know that `v$` is not initialised correctly, the very point of my question is to find out how to fix this problem. By the way, in Vuelidate 2.0, it's recommended you use `v$` rather than `$v` https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/migration_guide.html#v-instead-of-v

Answer (score -1):

To initialise Vuelidate when testing a Vue component with Vitest you can use the following approach:

**1. Add the following line to your test file:**

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
```

**2. Use Vuelidate in your test like so:**

```
it('click save button', async () => {

const wrapper = mount(MyComponent)

const v = Vuelidate.instance()

expect(v.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeTruthy()

await wrapper.find('[data-cy="accept-checkbox"]').trigger('click')

expect(v.formData.accepted.$invalid).toBeFalsy()

})
```

**3. Make sure that Vuelidate is initialised correctly within your Vue component like so:**

```
v$: useVuelidate({

$autoDirty: true

})
```

Comment: Your proposed import `import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';` is invalid in Vuelidate 2.0